# How to install Virtualbox kernel module in 16.04 LTSP chroot?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox, chroot, ltsp

Been trying to install Virtualbox for fat clients on a 16.04 server but can't get the kernel module to show up.

I tried this:

```
sudo ltsp-chroot -c -p
apt-get update && apt-get install virtualbox-qt virtualbox-dkms dkms
depmod
modprobe vboxdrv
```

modprobe vboxdrv returns:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic
```

There is no /etc/init.d/vboxdrv. I have tried every combination of apt-get remove virtualbox-qt virtualbox-dkms and reinstalling, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this not answer your questions, but may I know if you are already open your virtualbox & have issues when starting the vm. if yes, kindly include all the bugs & messages that appeared here. Kindly acknowledge us on this. Thanks.